# Replace line before pattern using sed or awk

Tags: text-processing

I have the following input in a `sacro.sql` file:

```
{ TABLE "informix".sacro_log row size = 64 number of columns = 3 index size = 0 }

{ unload file name = sacro00518.unl number of rows = 0 }

create table "informix".sacro_log
(
log_id serial not null constraint "informix".nnc_sac_log00,
log_type integer,
log_data text
);

revoke all on "informix".sacro_log from "public" as "informix";
```

I want to replace 2nd line above "create table "informix".sacro_log" with test

Example output I want:

```
{ TABLE "informix".sacro_log row size = 64 number of columns = 3 index size = 0 }

test

create table "informix".sacro_log
(
log_id serial not null constraint "informix".nnc_sac_log00,
log_type integer,
log_data text
);

revoke all on "informix".sacro_log from "public" as "informix";
```

Comment: `sed -z 's/[^\n]*\([[:space:]]*create\)/test\1/' sacro.sql`

Comment: Unfortunately the sed -z option is not valid in HP-UX

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/create table "informix"/i\
test
' data.in >data.out
```

This will create `data.out` with the following contents:

```
{ TABLE "informix".sacro_log row size = 64 number of columns = 3 index size = 0 }

{ unload file name = sacro00518.unl number of rows = 0 }

test
create table "informix".sacro_log
(
log_id serial not null constraint "informix".nnc_sac_log00,
log_type integer,
log_data text
);
```

The `i` ("insert") command in `sed` will insert the specified text before the matched pattern. The text inserted must follow a literal newline (GNU `sed` accepts `sed '/pattern/i text'` too).

Comment: How can i use a variable to search and replace above using                     sed '/create table "informix"/i\
test
' data.in >data.out

Comment: @ChristopherKarsten You should be able to `sed "/$pattern/i\ $text" data.in`.  Note the use of double rather single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if yu are still waiting for an answer, this could help.

```
awk -v newline=test -v trigger='create table "informix"' '
   {a[NR]=$0}
   NR>2 { if (index($0,trigger)>0) { a[NR-2]=newline; }}
   END { 
          for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) { print a[i] }
       }
   ' sacro.sql
```