# sed: Portable solution to match "any character but newline"

Tags: sed, regular-expression, posix

I can match newline by `\n`:

```
echo "one
two" | sed 'N;s/\n/_/g'
```

In GNU `sed`, I can use `[^\n]` to match any character but newline:

```
echo "one
two" | sed 'N;s/[^\n]/_/g'
```

This is very handy, but it violates POSIX. Other `sed` versions correctly answer `__n______`

Same thing with tab character, but there I can work around by using an actual tab character, preceeded by ctrl-v. But this doesn't work for newline:

```
echo "one
two" | sed 'N;s/[^
]/_/g'
```

gives me `unbalanced brackets`.

Using `[^[:cntrl:]]` only works while there are no other control characters I want to match.

So what's the correct way to match any character but newline in POSIX `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's a very neat way to handle this scenario in regular `sed`: interchange newline with some regular char, say, _ then do the [^_] and then flip back. I was wanting to post a solution to a problem that came up but was too lazy to post it but now let me put it here:

```
sed -e '
   /./!b

   :loop
      $q; N
   /\n$/bloop

   h

   /\ncreate table/!{
      s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p
      g;s/.*\(\n\)/\1/;D
   }

   g

   y/\n_/_\n/
      s/^[^_]*/test/
   y/\n_/_\n/

' input.data
```

---

[Problem statement for the above solution.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362213/replace-line-before-pattern-using-sed-or-awk)

Comment: This works, but I'd rather call this a nasty workaround than a neat solution. Ain't there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i have not understood your question correctly but i will take my chances to answer.

If you want to match everything except new line, a simple regex dot `.` does exactly this: match any char except new lines.

Let's try it with a non gnu sed:

```
$ cat file5
home
help
variables
compatibility

$ sed 's/./_/g' file5
____
____
_________
_____________

$ echo "one
two
three
four" |sed 's/./_/g'
___
___
_____
____
```

By the way, your very first sed example:

```
echo "one
two" | sed 'N;s/\n/_/g'
```

matches only the next new line, not every new line:

```
$ echo "one
> two
> three
> four" |sed 'N;s/\n/_/g'
one_two
three_four
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my example was simplified too much. As long as a text is processed line by line, it's useless to match newline or the complement set. But sometimes you use things like `sed 'H;1h;$! d;...` and then do operations on the whole text in one buffer. In those cases it may be useful to match anything but newline. How to do that elegantly?

Comment: @Philippos Even if it is like that (would be good to include a "buffer" example in your question) are you sure that using regex `.*` or `.+` will not work?

Comment: Very sure. `.` matches anything but NUL character, including newline. I'm preparing another question where this is needed with buffer example.

Comment: @Philippos Ok, better to see the buffer example. By the way if `.` matches everything except `null` you could pre-process the file like `tr '\n' '\0'` or even you could make it like `sed '......' <(tr '\n' '\0' <file)` (just thoughts)

Comment: Here is the [example where I need this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file/362442#362442). I'm afraid in posix `sed` it is not possible to use `\0` either.

Comment: Missing the `N` in the first examples, that doesn't create a newline in the pattern space. Also: it is the `N` that reads lines in pairs, not the regex. The regex will match all newlines.

Answer (score 2):

[The POSIX specification for basic regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) do not allow `\n` to match a literal newline (my emphasis below):

> The Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2017 specifies within the individual descriptions of those standard utilities employing regular expressions whether they permit matching of `<newline>` characters; **if not stated otherwise, the use of literal `<newline>` characters or any escape sequence equivalent in either patterns or matched text produces undefined results**.

Luckily, [the specification for the `sed` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) contains the following text, which states otherwise:

> The `sed` utility shall support the BREs described in XBD Basic Regular Expressions, with the following additions:
>
> [...]
>
> - The escape sequence `\n` shall match a `<newline>` embedded in the pattern space. [...]

This allows `sed` to match a literal newline  that has been embedded in the pattern space (from using e.g. `N`) using `\n` in a regular expression.

This leads me to believe that it would be fine to use `[^\n]` to match any single non-newline character.  This is also what the `sed` implementations on GNU systems, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, and Plan 9, does.

Comment: Thank you for this interpretation. It still conflicts with the statement "special characters [including backslash] shall lose their special meaning within a bracket expression." Anyhow, I didn’t ask for posix, but for portability. Unfortunally, my idea of "portable" covers more than three implementations … preferably all modern ones.

Comment: The `sed` from heirloom (from AT&T) http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html doesn't allow a `\n` inside a `[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `[[:alnum:][:punct:][:blank:]]` bracket expression:

```
echo "one
two" | sed 'N;s/[[:alnum:][:punct:][:blank:]]/_/g'
```

Outputs:

```
___
___
```

The `[:alnum:]` matches all alphanumeric chars, `[:punct:]` matches all punctuation and `[:blank:]` matches all horizontal whitespaces. All vertical whitespace is left out and does not get matched.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/lMg6Fn).

Comment: Thank you for the late answer. I think one should better use `[[:print:]]` instead, as in some locales there can be stuff like `[:graph:]`, which is neither `[:alnum:]` nor `[:punct:]`, but a problem remains if other control characters are allowed in the stream. Maybe `[[:print:]^A-`<tab>`^K-^Z]` with a literal TAB does the trick, but it's certainly less elegant than `[^\n]`. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: @Philippos Ok, then maybe `sed 'N;s/[^\x0A]/_/g'` will work. I thought the task was related to vertical whitespace in general.