# Replace a pattern if before a second pattern — keep the string between the two

Tags: text-processing, sed

Here is my code:

```
printf '%s' '{$aaa} \\{$bbb} \{$ccc}  {$ddd' | sed -r -e 's/(^|[^\\])\{\$/\1\$\{/g' -e 's/\\\\\{\$/\\\\\$\{/g'
```

and the result:

```
${aaa} \\${bbb} \{$ccc} ${ddd
```

The result is OK except for the last pattern, `{$ddd`, that shouldn't be replaced because it doesn't end with a closing brackets `}`.

How can I do that with sed?

Also if you know how to merge the two actual expressions, it's also welcomed (not that important to me)

Edit: note that the same is also done for the parentheses, `($foo)` to `$(foo)`

Comment: can you have input like `{$foo} {$abc {$bar}` and can there be spaces inside `{$...}`

Comment: For your question, yes. There can be virtually any characters between `{$` and `}`

Comment: can there be `{` and/or `}` characters inside? i.e nesting... also, what should be output for `{$foo} {$abc {$bar}` ?

Comment: Good catch. Thus inside `{$...}` there should only have `[aZ-_]` characters. This will fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the first task, only perform the change for closed `{}`:

```
printf '%s' '{$aaa} \\{$bbb} \{$ccc}  {$ddd' | sed 's/{$\([^}]*\)}/${\1}/g'
```

This is, everything after the `{$` up to the closing `}`  is put in `\(\)`, so we can backreference it in the replacement string as `\1`. Output:

```
${aaa} \\${bbb} \${ccc}  {$ddd
```

Now, about the backslash-escaping. Your solution works for `\{$aaa}` (don't touch) and `\\{$aaa}` (replace), but what about `\\\{$aaa}`? It will perform the change, which is probably not desired.

So I suggest to get rid of all double-backslashes first. We replace them by a character combination that cannot be part of the string, `#1` as an example, and change it back in the end. This way we can concentrate on the single backslash only:

```
printf '%s' '{$aaa} \\{$bbb} \{$ccc} \\\{$eee} {$ddd' | sed 's/\\\\/#1/g;s/{$\([^}]*\)}/${\1}/g;s/#1/\\\\/g'
```

And finally we can change `\{` to `#2` and replace it back at the end to get it out of our way:

```
printf '%s' '{$aaa} \\{$bbb} \{$ccc} \\\{$eee} {$ddd' | sed 's/\\\\/#1/g;s/\\{/#2/g;s/{$\([^}]*\)}/${\1}/g;s/#2/\\{/g;s/#1/\\\\/g'
```

Result: `${aaa} \\${bbb} \{$ccc} \\\{$eee} {$ddd`

And this will work for any number of backslashes.

But if there is no character like `#` you can freely use? You can use the newline, because a newline can't be part of a line. Since you seem to use GNU `sed`, you can do

```
printf '%s' '{$aaa} \\{$bbb} \{$ccc} \\\{$eee} {$ddd' | sed 's/\\\\/\n1/g;s/\\{/\n2/g;s/{$\([^}]*\)}/${\1}/g;s/\n2/\\{/g;s/\n1/\\\\/g'
```

If this should run on a POSIX `sed`, you need a [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362401/sed-portable-solution-to-match-any-character-but-newline)

Comment: Thank you for this nice explanation, your answer do perfectly what I would like!
For the POSIX compliance, as long as it works on busybox's sed (which is the case), all's good.

Comment: Also, do you know how to do the same with parentheses in the same expression? If not, no worry, I can simply add an other expression with `-e`.

Comment: I've found myself thanks to your answer:
 `sed 's/\\\\/\n1/g;s/\\(/\n2/g;s/($\([^)]*\))/$(\1)/g;s/\n2/\\(/g;s/\\{/\n2/g;s/{$\([^}]*\)}/${\1}/g;s/\n2/\\{/g;s/\n1/\\\\/g'`

Answer (score 1):

Using POSIX `sed` you can do your task as follows:

```
sed -e '
   # case for {$var}
   s/ \(\(\\\\\)\{0,\}\){\$\([^ }]*\)}/ \1${\3}/g
   s/^\(\(\\\\\)\{0,\}\){\$\([^ }]*\)}/\1${\3}/

   # case for ($var)
   s/ \(\(\\\\\)\{0,\}\)(\$\([^ )]*\))/ \1$(\3)/g
   s/^\(\(\\\\\)\{0,\}\)(\$\([^ )]*\))/\1$(\3)/
' input_file
```

Assuming spaces the only whitespace in the file. Of course, we can tackle with TAB and leave that as an exercise for the OP. With the extensions available in `GNU sed` we can further simplify the above, but I wanted to give a `POSIX` solution to give it greater applicability.

Comment: I also care like you about wide availability across POSIX systems, thank you for your alternative answer.