# Replacing multiple words in tab delimited file with alternative words

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a tab-delimited file with codes (e.g. ctc, nmg, nml) indicating organisms (File_1):

```
522 ctc:CTC00972    -   506 3.20E-138   
522 nmg:Nmag_3027   -   561 4.70E-73
522 nml:Namu_3564   -   566 1.80E-146
```

I also have a tab-delimited file that links the codes to the organism names (File_2):

```
ctc  Clostridium_tetani_E88
nla  Neisseria_lactamica
nmg  Natrialba_magadii
```

How can I replace the codes in File_1 with the organism names in File_2?

Desired output:

```
522 Clostridium_tetani_E88:CTC00972 -   506 3.20E-138   
522 Natrialba_magadii:Nmag_3027     -   561 4.70E-73
522 Neisseria_lactamica:Namu_3564   -   566 1.80E-146
```

Keeping in mind that there are thousands of these codes in the full data set and that the order of the organisms is not the same in File_1 and File_2.

Comment: Your data doesn't appear to be consistent with the desired output (`nla` not `nml` corresponds to `Neisseria_lactamica`)

Comment: Similar questions have been answered hundreds of times.

Answer (score 1):

It's really just a variant of the "build a lookup table from one file; use it when processing the other file", with the wrinkle that the lookup key needs to be split from the second field. You could do that in `awk` for example:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} 
  NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$2; next
  } 
  {
    split($2,b,":"); 
    if (b[1] in a) $2 = a[b[1]]":"b[2]
  } 1' File_2 File_1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job with `sed`:

```
sed '/^[a-z]*[[:cntrl:]].*/{s/[[:cntrl:]]/###/;H;d;}
 G
 s/\([a-z]*\)\(:.*\n\)\1###\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)/\3\2/
 P
 d' file_2 file_1
```

It's an adoption of [this generic solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file). See there for an explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$2 in a{$2=a[$2]":"$3;$3=""}1' File_2 FS="[ |:]" File_1
```

The output:

```
522 Clostridium_tetani_E88:CTC00972     -   506 3.20E-138   
522 Natrialba_magadii:Nmag_3027    -   561 4.70E-73
522 nml:Namu_3564   -   566 1.80E-146
```

Note, that `nml` and `nla` codes don't have matches between the 2 input files

Comment: I like the one line approach. Could you explain it a bit more, so that it can be modified? For example, how would you change the command if you wanted to replace words in column 1 instead of column 2 or how would you modify the command if column 2 didn't possess the section after the ":"?

Comment: @P.tin, 1) *to replace words in column 1 instead of column 2* - move columns as per your needs `$1=a[$1]`. 2) is the 2nd field of file1 doesn't have `:` you'll need to rearrange field separator `FS="[ |:]"`. If you have new requirements - it should be as new question