# Compare two files and modify input upon match

Tags: text-processing

I want to compare `file1` with `file2`.

`file1` contains a set of pathnames and `file2` contains a set of words.

If any pathname contains any of the words in the second file, it should be commented out by prepending the line with `//`.

`file1`:

```
xxx/AAA.tmp.v
xxx/BBB.tmp.v
xxx/CCC.tmp.v
```

`file2`:

```
BBB
CCC
FFF
```

Desired output in a new file:

```
xxx/AAA.tmp.v
// xxx/BBB.tmp.v
// xxx/CCC.tmp.v
```

Comment: is the data to be matched from file2 always in the form of `/data.` in file1? solution would be easier if that is the case... and it is better to add your efforts made and point out where you got stuck...

Comment: @Sundeep:
your script no error syntax and result exactly same my expectation, thanks a lot. 
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {for(line in a)if($0 ~ line)$0="// "$0} 1' file2 file1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk`.

```
awk -F"[/.]" 'NR==FNR{seen[$0];next} 
    ($2 in seen){print "// "$0; next}1
' file2 file1
```

- `-F"[/.]"` defines fields delimiters as slash `/` or point `.`.
- `NR==FNR` this is true always for first input data (here file2), **R**ecord **N**umber==**F**ile **R**ecord **N**umber.
- `seen[$0];next` if above is true, then hold entire line of file2 into array named `seen`, then read next line `next` (actually goto first and run this block again until `NR!=FNR`)
- `($2 in seen){print "// "$0; next}1` this is only apply for second input file (here file1), and looking for the `seen` array if contains same string as column#2 `$2` in file1, then print entire line of file1 with pre-appended `//`, and goto `next` check condition again until it's match, otherwise print the entire line with `1` condition (that's enable `awk`'s default action).

Comment: @αғsнιη: Thanks a lot, it's very clear

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can do it like this:

```
sed '/tmp/!{H;d;}
G;s/$/\
/;s_.*\(..*\).*\n\1\n_// &_
P;d' file2 file1
```

You collect the patterns of file2 in the hold space and for each line of file1 you append that collection and check with backreferences whether the pattern is found in the line.

For a more detailed explanation see [this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file).

Note that I used the string `tmp` as indication that we are in file1; you may need to adapt that to your actual case. The strange substitution starting in line 2 adds a newline to the end so we know that each pattern will be surrounded by newlines.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philippos, 
and get multi choice with your script and detail information