# is a directory error

Tags: sed, directory, gawk

I'm having some problems running my current program. I need to take a file of customers information (each line is a new customer) and substitute it into a template. Each customer info will created a file from the template and will be named using the customer's email and placed into the Email subdirectory using `awk` and `sed`. Right now my program is not 'doing anything' except printing the line `./test.bash: line 19: Emails/: Is a directory` .

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 set -e
  3
  4 if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  5     echo "Illegal number of parameters. Usage:./test1.bash <mm/dd/yyyy>"
  6     exit 1
  7 fi
  8
  9 OUTPUT_DIR="Emails"
 10 details="p4Customer.txt"
 11 template="template.txt"
 12 date=$1
 13 if [ ! -d "$OUTPUT_DIR" ]; then
 14     mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"
 15 fi
 16
 17 gawk -f g2.awk -v date="$date" "$details" | while read detail;
 18 do
 19     sed "$detail" "$template" > "$OUTPUT_DIR/$email"
 20 done;
```

awk file

```
  1 BEGIN{ FS=",";}
  2 {
  3     email=$1;
  4     fullname=$2;
  5     title=$3;
  6     n=split(fullname,A," ");
  7     name=A[n];
  8     amount_owed=$5;
  9     if($5>$4)
 10         printf "s/EMAIL/%s/;s/FULLNAME/%s/;s/TITLE/%s/;s/NAME/%s/;s/AMOUNT/%s/;s/DATE/%s/\n", email, fullname, title, name, amount_owed, date;
 11 }
 12 END{}
```

Comment: Why do you use `$email` but not set it to anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
sed "$detail" "$template" > "$OUTPUT_DIR/$email"
```

uses the parameter `email` which is defined for `awk` only what does not affect the shell environment.

Comment: I see what you mean about the shell environment variables. Since Im using `awk` to set the variables and to create a `sed` file, is there anyway I could get the customers email from the file while doing that, or would I maybe have to run a read loop on the file at the same time also to get each individual customers email were the `>"OUTPUT_DIR/$email"` is? @Hauke Laging

Comment: Perhaps a new `awk` command to print the email or a `grep` command?

Comment: @below_avg_st what you probably are looking for here is `source`: https://ss64.com/bash/source.html This runs the file in the shell that called the `source` command as opposed to a subshell. A benefit of this is that if you have a file that just sets variables, you can use `source` to pull them all into a different shell.

Comment: @below_avg_st Why would you use `awk` at all in order to generate `sed` commands? `awk` is the mightier tool and can do the `sed` work.

Comment: My teacher wants us to use only awk, sed, and bash in this practice example.

Comment: You can demonstrate to your teacher that only `awk` is required. And teach him about UUOS and UUOB (Useless Use of Sed , Useless Use of Bash), in regard to UUOC. Imagine your file contains thousand and thousand of lines, you solution will be very slow due to thousand and thousand of `sed` process spawning. School is good time to learn about elegancy and efficiency. If i had a very bad mind i would hope for you, you didn't pay much for such a poor teaching.

Comment: @below_avg_st To me "to use only awk, sed, and bash" does not sound like "have to use both awk and sed and bash".

Comment: This look like part of a "fill templates with parameters defined in another file" task. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file) for an example how to solve this with `sed` only.