# compare two column of two different CSV file & merge the output

Tags: linux, awk, perl, csv

TABLE1.csv

```
 DATE,      TIMESTAMP, ID,  START TIME, END TIME, DURATION
2019-04-05, 13:57:19,  1607,13:06:42,   13:07:12, 00:00:30
2019-04-05, 13:58:00,  2327,13:57:26,   13:57:43, 00:00:17
2019-04-24, 12:30:00,  1836,11:20:01,   12:30:00, 01:09:59
2019-04-24, 12:30:00,  1836,11:20:01,   12:30:00, 01:09:59
2019-04-24, 15:30:01,  1836,14:50:01,   15:30:01, 00:40:00
2019-04-24, 15:30:01,  1836,14:50:01,   15:30:01, 00:40:00
```

TABLE2.csv

```
KEY, ID,   NAME
407, 1607, RECORD1
1127,2327, RECORD2
636, 1836, RECORD3
664, 1864, RECORD4
703, 1903, RECORD5
```

Match Coloumn 3 from TABLE1.csv and Coloumn 2 from TABLE2.csv & output required as given below:

```
 DATE,      TIMESTAMP, ID,   NAME,    START TIME, END TIME, DURATION
2019-04-05, 13:57:19,  1607, RECORD1, 13:06:42,   13:07:12, 00:00:30
2019-04-05, 13:58:00,  2327, RECORD2, 13:57:26,   13:57:43, 00:00:17
2019-04-24, 12:30:00,  1836, RECORD3, 11:20:01,   12:30:00, 01:09:59
2019-04-24, 12:30:00,  1836, RECORD3, 11:20:01,   12:30:00, 01:09:59
2019-04-24, 15:30:01,  1836, RECORD3, 14:50:01,   15:30:01, 00:40:00
2019-04-24, 15:30:01,  1836, RECORD3, 14:50:01,   15:30:01, 00:40:00
```

I have tried every example of

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` one collects the replacements of `TABLE2.csv` in hold space and then performs the adding of the column:

```
sed 's/^[^,]*, *\([0-9]*,[^,]*\)$/\1/
T2
H;d
:2
G
s/\([^,]*,[^,]*, *\)\([0-9]*,\)\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)\n.*\n\2\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)/\1\2\4, \3/
P;d' TABLE2.csv TABLE1.csv
```

You have to add something for the changed headline, if neccessary.

- `s/^[^,]*, *\([0-9]*,[^,]*\)$/\1/` does extract the second and third column from `TABLE2.csv` lines
- `T2` jumps to `:2`, if no replacement was made (thus, for `TABLE2.csv` lines)
- Changed `TABLE2.csv` lines are appended to the `H`old space and then `d`eleted (stop execution for this line)
- `:2` is the jump mark. Everything that follows is done for `TABLE1.csv` lines only
- `G` appends the lookup table from the hold space to the pattern space
- `s/\([^,]*,[^,]*, *\)\([0-9]*,\)\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)\n.*\n\2\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)/\1\2\4, \3/` looks for occurences of the ID (`[0-9]*,`) in the lookup table and adds the matching field
- `P` prints the line (without the added lookup table) and `d` stops execution for the line.

For more detailed explanation refer to [How to perform replacements defined in one file on another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file)

Comment: SOLVED , Its WORKED

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this

```
awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '
    NR == FNR { name[$2] = $3; next }
    { $3 = $3 OFS name[$3]; print }
' TABLE{2,1}.csv
```

outputs

```
 DATE, TIMESTAMP, ID, NAME, START TIME, END TIME, DURATION
2019-04-05, 13:57:19, 1607, RECORD1, 13:06:42, 13:07:12, 00:00:30
2019-04-05, 13:58:00, 2327, RECORD2, 13:57:26, 13:57:43, 00:00:17
2019-04-24, 12:30:00, 1836, RECORD3, 11:20:01, 12:30:00, 01:09:59
2019-04-24, 12:30:00, 1836, RECORD3, 11:20:01, 12:30:00, 01:09:59
2019-04-24, 15:30:01, 1836, RECORD3, 14:50:01, 15:30:01, 00:40:00
2019-04-24, 15:30:01, 1836, RECORD3, 14:50:01, 15:30:01, 00:40:00
```

That reads TABLE2 first and maps the ID to the NAME.
Then reads TABLE1 and adds the NAME to the ID field.

Formatting the spacing of your columns is left up to you.

Comment: OUTPUT is: , 13:06:42, 13:07:12, 00:00:30RECORD1
, 13:57:26, 13:57:43, 00:00:17RECORD2
, 11:20:01, 12:30:00, 01:09:59RECORD3
, 11:20:01, 12:30:00, 01:09:59RECORD3
, 14:50:01, 15:30:01, 00:40:00lRECORD3