# Replace using sed not working as expected

Tags: sed

I need to run search/replace function on a large ascii text file.  A short excerpt from input file:

```
gene_id "MSTRG.1";
gene_id "MSTRG.1";
gene_id "MSTRG.2";
gene_id "MSTRG.3";
```

The `MSTRG` string will be replaced with another ID which is present in a template file:

```
MSTRG.1 AT1G01030
MSTRG.2 AT1G01010
MSTRG.3 AT1G01035
```

A simple while loop is iterating over each line of the template and making replacements:

```
while read bef aft
do
  echo "Searching for $bef"
  echo "Replacing with $aft"
  sed "s/$bef/$aft/g" input > output
done < template
```

What is happening is that the `MSTRG.2` and onward entries are being replaced correctly, but `MSTRG.1` remains unchanged. The output looks as follows:

```
gene_id "MSTRG.1";
gene_id "MSTRG.1";
gene_id "AT1G01010";
gene_id "AT1G01035";
```

### Update

Here is  what I did in the end.

```
while read bef aft
do
  sed -i "s/$bef/$aft/g" input
done < template
```

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that `MSTRG.2` is being replaced in the final `output` file.  You are clobbering the file in each iteration, so I'd expect that only the last replacement would be visible. Just do the redirection to `output` after the loop instead of in each iteration (just like you're already redirecting the loop's input from `template`).  I'm not posting this as an answer since I'm not sure why you say (or how it's possible) that `MSTRG.2` is being replaced.

Comment: Not sure I understand. How do I redirect the output after the loop is finished?

Comment: `while ...; do ...; done <template >output`. And redirect the two `echo` calls to standard error to avoid getting them in the output: `echo ... >&2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform replacements defined in one file on another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file)

Comment: You don‘t need the `read` loop at all, but do it in one pass by adapting the scheme given in the linked answer.

Comment: The answer you linked to is far more complicated than a simple while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are clobbering the output file in each iteration of the loop, leaving only the most recent changes in `output` and none of the earlier ones.

Instead, you can easily transform your `template` file into a series of `sed` commands:

```
$ awk '{ printf("s/%s/%s/g\n", $1, $2) }' template
s/MSTRG.1/AT1G01030/g
s/MSTRG.2/AT1G01010/g
s/MSTRG.3/AT1G01035/g
```

... and then apply these to your file:

```
$ awk '{ printf("s/%s/%s/g\n", $1, $2) }' template | sed -f - input
gene_id "AT1G01030";
gene_id "AT1G01030";
gene_id "AT1G01010";
gene_id "AT1G01035";
```

Some implementations of `sed` don't recognise `-` as meaning standard input.  To use this approach with such a `sed`, replace `-f -` with `-f /dev/stdin`.

Or, you could just do it all in `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR { pat[$1] = $2; next } { for (p in pat) gsub(p, pat[p]); print }' template input
gene_id "AT1G01030";
gene_id "AT1G01030";
gene_id "AT1G01010";
gene_id "AT1G01035";
```

Note that all of the above variations uses what is in the first column of `template` as a *regular expression*, meaning that the `.` (dot) will match *any* character.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overwriting the output file in each loop iteration, you could copy the input file as output file and operate on this output file.

With `sed`'s `-i` option changes are written in-place to the same file, so previous replacements don't get lost:

```
cp input output
while read bef aft
do
  echo "Searching for $bef"
  echo "Replacing with $aft"
  sed -i "s/$bef/$aft/g" output
done < template
```

Comment: Precisely what I just did (and posted an update to my question).  Thank you.

Comment: Yep, you were too fast! I just realized your update after my post.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -i

use strict;

# The %re hash holds the regexp searches and replacement strings.
my %re = ();

my $tfile = shift;
open(TEMPLATE, "<", $tfile) || die "couldn't open $tfile for read: $!\n";
while(<TEMPLATE>) {
   chomp;
   my ($search,$replace) = split;
   $re{qr/$search/} = $replace;
};
close(TEMPLATE);

while (<>) {
  foreach my $s (keys %re) {
    s/$s/$re{$s}/g;
  };
  print;
}
```

This reads the `template` file and builds up an associative array (aka "hash") called `%re` of regular expression searches and replaces.

Then it loops over every remaining filename on the command line (e.g. `input`) and performs all of those search and replace operations on every line of input.  It uses `qr//` to pre-compile the regular expressions - this is only a trivial optimisation if there aren't many lines in `template`, but can result in a very significant speedup if there are many lines.

The `-i` on the `#!/usr/bin/perl -i` line causes perl to make in-place edits on the input files, rather than just print the changes to stdout.   Change this to, e.g., `-i.bak` if you want it to keep a backup copy of the files before they were changed.

Save as, e.g., `cryptic0.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x cryptic0.pl` and run it like this:

```
$ ./cryptic0.pl template input
```

The script will not produce any output on the terminal.  Instead, it will edit the input file(s).

For example, your `input` file will be changed to:

```
$ cat input
gene_id "AT1G01030";
gene_id "AT1G01030";
gene_id "AT1G01010";
gene_id "AT1G01035";
```

BTW, this script will change all matches on all lines to their appropriate replacement string.  If you are certain that there can only be **one** match on any given line, you can speed it up by changing this line:

```
s/$s/$re{$s}/g;
```

to this:

```
s/$s/$re{$s}/ && last;
```

This causes the script to skip out of the foreach loop to the `print` statement, and then move on to the next input line as soon as it has had one successful search & replace.

---

BTW, see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/7696) for why it's not a good idea to do text processing in with sh loops.   Use `awk` or `perl` or `sed` or anything else instead of `sh` or `bash`.