# File Comparison

Tags: linux, python, yaml

I have two files with FILE1 containing lots of lines and FILE2 with KEY VALUE parms. I need to compare FILE2 with FILE1 and if there is match the corresponding word in FILE1 should be replace with next column in FILE2.

Example:

FILE1:

```
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
PARM1
PARM2
PARM3
PARM4
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->
```

FILE2:

```
PARM1 mmddyy
PARM2 hhmmss
PARM3 awsid
PARM4 cc
```

So for every match from FILE2 in FILE1, the corresponding word in FILE1 should be replace with 2nd column in FILE2. So the desired output should like:

```
<SOME YAML CODE
-------------->
mmddyy
hhmmss
awsid
cc
<END OF YAML CODE
---------------->
```

I tried using sed with limited knowledge but not achieving the desired output.

Appreciate your time and support

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make your post easier to read.

Comment: Can any of the target strings appear in the "YAML code"? For example, could you have `PARM1` anywhere in the YAML code? As part of another word? As a random string? And can the `PARM` appear as the second or third or Nth word on a line or will it always be the first? Can there be other words on the same line?

Comment: yes Terdon, the target strings could be anywhere

Comment: Could you please show an example that is _actually_ YAML? It would make it easier to determine whether it's worth while using a YAML parser to read it.  What you have is some template (your YAML file) and you want to instantiate it using the values in your second file. There are tools for doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform replacements defined in one file on another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{k[$1]=$2;}
    NR!=FNR{if($1 in k){$0=k[$1]};print}
' file2 file1
```

Save an array of fields from `file2` and if found in `file1`, replace the line (`$0`) with the content of the corresponding array.

Comment: You are replacing the entire line here though, not just the word. This time I did read the question! :) "for every match from FILE2 in FILE1, the corresponding word in FILE1 should be replace with 2nd column in FILE2"

Comment: might be, but then this is a very bad example text....

Comment: pLumo-- you are genious and saved my day. This worked like charm, appreciate your help. Thankyou

Comment: just realized that FILE1 has some lines like <some code>_PARM1, and the desired output should be

<some code>_mmddyy

Any idea on this please