# Replace values in fifth column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have multiple text

```
Name 1:10:34 date short_id 10 
Name 1:10:45 date short_id 10
Name 1:20:54 date short_id 20
Name 1:30:43 date short_id 30
Name 1:40:43 date short_id 40
Name 1:40:13 date short_id 40
Name 1:20:01 date short_id 20
Name 1:10:01 date short_id 10
```

I want to replace the fifth column , but when I use  `sed 's/\b10\b/user1/g'` the second column also changes

The output should look like this :

```
Name 1:10:34 date short_id user1
Name 1:10:45 date short_id user1
Name 1:20:54 date short_id user2
Name 1:30:43 date short_id user3
Name 1:40:43 date short_id user4
Name 1:40:13 date short_id user4
Name 1:20:01 date short_id user2
Name 1:10:01 date short_id user1
```

--- update ---

if there is no user1, there will be a name
and the second column is just time, it has nothing to do with the name

something like this

```
Name 1:10:34 date short_id John
Name 1:10:45 date short_id John
Name 1:20:54 date short_id Robert
Name 1:30:43 date short_id Jennifer
Name 1:40:43 date short_id Mary
Name 1:40:13 date short_id Mary
Name 1:20:01 date short_id Robert
Name 1:10:01 date short_id John
```

Comment: how can that `sed` command generate a **user2** ? can you  edit the OP with a exact copy/paste of the sed command used ?

Comment: Please format the sed command you tried as code as well to make it clear what you have tried.

Comment: You managed to confuse me. (-: Do you plan to write a `s`ubstitute for each user id/name or is there a file with some »translation table« which id is which user?

Answer (score 3):

Two more awk solutions.

```
$ awk '{$5="user"substr($5,1,1)}1' file
Name 1:10:34 date short_id user1
Name 1:10:45 date short_id user1
Name 1:20:54 date short_id user2
Name 1:30:43 date short_id user3
Name 1:40:43 date short_id user4
Name 1:40:13 date short_id user4
Name 1:20:01 date short_id user2
Name 1:10:01 date short_id user1
$
```

```
$ awk '{$5="user"$5/10}1' x1
Name 1:10:34 date short_id user1
Name 1:10:45 date short_id user1
Name 1:20:54 date short_id user2
Name 1:30:43 date short_id user3
Name 1:40:43 date short_id user4
Name 1:40:13 date short_id user4
Name 1:20:01 date short_id user2
Name 1:10:01 date short_id user1
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, unfortunally, `sed` doesn't know that `10` is `John`. So if you don't want to write another substitution for each user, you might want to use a second file `users.txt` with a translation table like this:

```
10 John
20 Robert
30 Jennifer
40 Mary
```

Then you feed both files into this `sed` command:

```
sed '/^[0-9]* [[:alnum:]]*$/{H;d;};G;s/ \([0-9]*\)\n.*\n\1 \([[:alnum:]]*\)/ \2/;P;d' users.txt yourfile.log
```

The translation table is read first and stored into the hold space. For the other files, the hold space with the translations is appended and the replacement is performed if possible. Then `P` prints the line only to the first line break, so no mess is printed if a user ID is unknown.

If you are interested in a more detailed explanation, see [How to perform replacements defined in one file on another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file) or feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'gsub(/0/, "", $5) { print $1, $2, $3, $4, "user" $5 }' INPUT
```

gsub removes number "0" in the 5th column. Then awk prints column 1-4, and combines word "user" with 5th column (there is no "," between "user" and $5).

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I had added explanation in my answer.

Comment: As I understand the question, `userx` is just a placeholder for actual user names.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to change is the last column you don't need the `g` modifier for global and you will want to add the `$` anchor to limit it to the last column.

I.e.: `sed 's/\b10$/user1/'`

That is assuming you'll want to change only the `10`.

If the 10, 20 etc. match directly to user 1,2 etc. something like the following may work:

`sed 's/\b\([1-4]\)0$/user\1/'`

Comment: Note that `10\b$` is the same as `10$`, and that you added the `g` modifiers in even though saying they're not needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.\).*/\1 user\2/' input_file
Name 1:10:34 date short_id user1
Name 1:10:45 date short_id user1
Name 1:20:54 date short_id user2
Name 1:30:43 date short_id user3
Name 1:40:43 date short_id user4
Name 1:40:13 date short_id user4
Name 1:20:01 date short_id user2
Name 1:10:01 date short_id user1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '!($NF in users){ users[$NF]="user"(++cnt) } { $NF=users[$NF] } 1' file
Name 1:10:34 date short_id user1
Name 1:10:45 date short_id user1
Name 1:20:54 date short_id user2
Name 1:30:43 date short_id user3
Name 1:40:43 date short_id user4
Name 1:40:13 date short_id user4
Name 1:20:01 date short_id user2
Name 1:10:01 date short_id user1
```

The above assumes you want each user to get a unique ID based on the order they appear in the input. If that's not what you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'given .words -> $w {put "$w.[0..3] ", (S/ (\d+) /user{$0.substr(0,1)}/ with $w.[4]) };'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'put .[0..3], " ", (S/ (\d+) /user{$0.substr(0,1)}/ with .[4]) given .words;'
```

The Raku code here breaks lines into whitespace-separated `words`. The first 4 columns (index `.[0..3]`) are out`put`. Then digits in the 5th column are matched, and substitute with the word `user` followed by the first digit.

*[A nicety of the `with .[4]` clause in the column 5 substitution is that it tolerates missing values in that column].*

Sample Input:

```
Name 1:10:34 date short_id 10 
Name 1:10:45 date short_id 10
Name 1:20:54 date short_id 20
Name 1:30:43 date short_id 30
Name 1:40:43 date short_id 40
Name 1:40:13 date short_id 40
Name 1:20:01 date short_id 20
Name 1:10:01 date short_id 10
```

Sample Output:

```
Name 1:10:34 date short_id user1
Name 1:10:45 date short_id user1
Name 1:20:54 date short_id user2
Name 1:30:43 date short_id user3
Name 1:40:43 date short_id user4
Name 1:40:13 date short_id user4
Name 1:20:01 date short_id user2
Name 1:10:01 date short_id user1
```

https://raku.org