# How can I replace multiple substrings from multiple lines in a file matching a pattern from a different file?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, python, perl

I have a file that contains multiple IP addresses and hostnames, and another file that contains some folders with many IP addresses per line.

**ip_hostname.txt**

```
host1 10.1.1.1
host2 10.2.2.2
host3 10.3.3.3
host100 10.50.50.50
```

**path_ips.txt**

```
/path1/foo/bar 10.1.1.1 10.2.2.2 10.3.3.3
/path2/foo/bar 10.3.3.3 10.7.7.7
/path3/foo/bar 10.4.4.4 10.8.8.8 10.29.29.29 10.75.75.75
/path100/foo/bar 10.60.60.60
```

I want to replace the IP addresses from **path_ips.txt** file with the hostname from **ip_hostname.txt** file that matches each IP address.

Desired output for **path_ips.txt**

```
/path1/foo/bar host1 host2 host3
/path2/foo/bar host3 host7
/path3/foo/bar host4 host8 host29 host75
/path100/foo/bar host60
```

I tried to do it with sed in a nested *while read* loop as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r line
do
IP=$(echo $line| awk '{print $1}')
HN=$(echo $line| awk '{print $2}')

        while read -r line2
        do
               sed -i "s/$IP/$HN/g" path_ips.txt
        echo $line2 #to see the progress
        done < path_ips.txt

done < ip_hostname.txt
```

And it worked well the first time when the list of IP addresses and hostnames is not so large, but when I tried to do it using a larger list in **ip_hostname.txt** file, it behaves strangely and the outcome is not as desired. It is needless to mention that it takes too long for it to finish.

Is there a better and efficient way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform replacements defined in one file on another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file)

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your script is that you run a separate `sed` command for each IP address that is matched, which makes the script really slow when the file is big.

You also have a nested loop, so you get `O(N*M)` time complexity in your algorithm.

A better approach would be to use `awk` to do the replacing, so that you can do all the replacements in a single pass:

```bash
$ awk 'NR==FNR{h[$2]=$1;next}{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i in h) $i = h[$i]}1' ip_hostname.txt path_ips.txt 
/path1/foo/bar host1 host2 host3
/path2/foo/bar host3 host7
/path3/foo/bar host4 host8 host29 host75
...
/path100/foo/bar host60
```

or in a more readable format

```bash
awk '
    NR == FNR {
      h[$2] = $1
      next
    }
    {
      for (i=2; i<= NF; i++)
        if ($i in h)
          $i = h[$i]
    }
    1
' ip_hostname.txt path_ips.txt
```

This should have a complexity of `O((N+M)lon(N))` where `N` is the size of file `ip_hostname.txt` and `M` is the size of file `path_ips.txt`. Note that `ip_hostname.txt` should be able to fit in memory for this to work, but it shouldn't be a problem on a modern computer, unless it is several GBs in size.

Comment: You may want to start the inner `for` loop at 2 rather than 1, to skip the pathname field. Also, you will have to explicitly assume that the pathname field does not contain whitespaces.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thank you for the suggestion about the starting index, regarding the pathname having whitespace, this will only be a problem if one of the words in the pathname is an IP address, but I don't see an easy way out of this.

Comment: Yes, the delimiter is unspecified in the question, so there's an additional issue with pathnames containing double spaces.  These would be shrunk to single spaces when the new lines are written out by `awk`. Assuming that the pathnames are "nice" would resolve this.

Comment: to anyone new to awk: if confused about `NR == FNR {} {} 1`, read https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ 'Two-file processing' part

Answer (score 2):

This can be done entirely in sed, but the awk answer is generally more readable.

```
#file toggle
1{x;s:^$:<IPs>:;x}
/^EOF$/{x;s:<IPs>:<paths>:;x;d}

#store hostname file
x;/<IPs>/{x;H;d}

#process path file
x;s: :>&:;s:$: :;G
:loop
    s:>( [^ ]+)( .*<paths>.*)\n([^ ]+)\1: \3>\2\n\3\1:
tloop
s:> .*::p
```

As shown in the example, the code assumes space to be the file delimiter. That means the answer will most likely be wrong if there are paths containing space.

This was tested with GNU sed, but you might have a different sed version. If this doesn't run, let me know.

**Run:**

```
sed -nrf SCRIPT_FILE ip_hostname.txt <(echo EOF) path_ips.txt > output.txt
```

Note: `<(echo EOF)` is used to tell my script when the first input file ends.

Answer (score 2):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    map[$2] = $1
    next
}
match($0,/([[:space:]]+([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})+$/) {
    path = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    $0 = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        $i = ($i in map ? map[$i] : $i)
    }
    $0 = path OFS $0
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk ip_hostname.txt path_ips.txt
/path1/foo/bar host1 host2 host3
/path3/foo/bar 10.4.4.4 10.8.8.8 10.29.29.29 10.75.75.75
/path100/foo/bar 10.60.60.60
```

That will work even if the path contains spaces unless the file name part of the path can end with a space followed by a string that looks like an IP address, e.g. `/path/foo/bar 1.1.1.1` where the `1.1.1.1` is not an IP address but instead part of the name of the file `bar 1.1.1.1`. If that can happen then you need some other format for ip_hostname.txt to separate paths from IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

We will use the ip_hostnames file to build a series of sed commands in the BRE regex syntax. These commands are basic s/ip/hostname/. Care is taken to escape the contents that go into the left hand and right hand sides of the s/ip/host/ commands.

These sed commands are then used by a second sed that operates on the ip_paths file and the substitutions are performed there.

```
< ip_hostname.txt \
sed -e '
  1i s/$/ /
  $a s/ $//
  h;s/ .*//;s:[\&/]:\\&:g
  x;s/.* //;s/[.]/[.]/g;G
  s:\(.*\)\n\(.*\):s/ \1 / \2 /:
' - |  sed -f - path_ips.txt
```

Sample contents of the sed commands that are generated for this data set

```
s/$/ /
s/ 10[.]1[.]1[.]1 / host1 /
s/ 10[.]2[.]2[.]2 / host2 /
s/ 10[.]3[.]3[.]3 / host3 /
s/ 10[.]4[.]4[.]4 / host4 /
s/ 10[.]7[.]7[.]7 / host7 /
...
s/ $//
```

Answer (score 1):

The following perl script reads in the first input file (`ip_hostname.txt`), and builds an associative array (hash) called %IPs, where the keys are the IP addresses and the values are the hostnames.

As a performance optimisation, each key of the `%IPs` hash is actually a pre-compiled regex (`qr//`) of the IP address, with word boundary markers (`\b`) and escaped metacharacters (`\Q` & `\E`) so that `.` means a literal `.` rather than any character.

Pre-compiling the regexes will minimise the amount of CPU time spent compiling the regex, down from one per IP address per line of path_ips.txt (i.e. number of lines in `ip_hostname.txt` multiplied by the number of lines in `path_ips.txt`) to just one per IP address.   This will make a significant difference in performance if either or both files are large.

Variable `$first` is used to keep track of whether the script is reading the first file or not. It is initialised to true (1) before the main `while` loop and set to false (0) at the end of each input file.

After processing the first file, for each line of the second file (`path_ips.txt`), it iterates over the `%IPs` hash to search for each IP address and replace it with the associated host name.  Then it prints the (possibly modified) input line.

Only matching IP addresses on each line are changed, everything else (including whitespace) is left as-is.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %IPs;
my $first = 1;

while(<>) {
  if ($first) {
    chomp;                   # strip \n or \r\n line-endings
    my ($host,$ip) = split;  # assumes whitespace delimited input
    $IPs{qr/\b\Q$ip\E\b/} = $host;

  } else {
    foreach my $ip (keys %IPs) {
      s/$ip/$IPs{$ip}/g;
    };
    print;
  };
  $first = 0 if eof;
};

#use Data::Dump qw(dd);
#dd \%IPs;
```

Save as, e.g., `map-hostnames.pl` and make executable with `chmod +x`.

Sample output (with an `ip_hostname.txt` file edited to contain mappings for all the IPs/hosts mentioned in your question):

```
$ ./map-hostnames.pl ip_hostname.txt path_ips.txt 
/path1/foo/bar host1 host2 host3
/path2/foo/bar host3 host7
/path3/foo/bar host4 host8 host29 host75
/path100/foo/bar host60
```

---

BTW, if you want to see what the `%IPs` hash looks like, uncomment the last two lines of the script (requires the [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-Dump) module to be installed).  It'll look like this, but with the contents of your real `ip_hostname.txt` file:

```
{
  "(?^:\\b10\\.1\\.1\\.1\\b)"    => "host1",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.29\\.29\\.29\\b)" => "host29",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.2\\.2\\.2\\b)"    => "host2",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.3\\.3\\.3\\b)"    => "host3",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.4\\.4\\.4\\b)"    => "host4",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.50\\.50\\.50\\b)" => "host100",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.60\\.60\\.60\\b)" => "host60",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.75\\.75\\.75\\b)" => "host75",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.7\\.7\\.7\\b)"    => "host7",
  "(?^:\\b10\\.8\\.8\\.8\\b)"    => "host8",
}
```